# python and django timezone didn't match

Tags: python, django, datetime, timezone

when i `datetime` my python i got the exact timezone in my country.

```
>>> import datetime
>>> now = datetime.datetime.now()
>>> str(now)
'2012-02-03 16:21:29.898276'
```

but when i `datetime` my python django shell, i got this:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> now = datetime.datetime.now()
>>> str(now)
'2012-02-03 02:22:44.740254'
```

how can i configure django python to get the exact timezone in my country?

thanks in advance ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check your settings.py for the [TIME_ZONE](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#time-zone) settings.

The available choices can be [seen here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/datetime-keywords.html#DATETIME-TIMEZONE-SET-TABLE). Edit accordingly in your settings.py (can be found in the project root)